# Search log entry in a file more than 6 months old and delete them from the file

Tags: bash, shell

What I want to do here is, I have log file which gets append every day. I want to delete log entries more than 6 month old from a file. I am able to delete 6 months old entry but what about entry more than 6 months, this where I am not able to find solution. Can someone get me to that logic and give some hint?

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern=$(date -d "6 month ago" +%Y%m%d)
sed "/$pattern/d" /root/new/Logfile.log >> outputfile
```

What I want to do here is, it should also check `Logfile.log` entries more than 6 month old, where 4th column contains the date.

Sample Logfile.log pattern is given below:

```
ERROR     8245001       000 20141215  171010    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20141215  171010    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20150515  171010    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20150515  171010    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20161215  171011    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20161215  171011    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20161215  171011    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20161215  171011    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20171215  171012    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20171215  171012    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20171215  171012    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20180515  171012    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20180515  171119    Patch output error in output  
ERROR     8245001       000 20180515  171119    Patch output error in output
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that neither your question nor this answer is `bash` specific. You're asking about strategy and the meat of your sample code is `sed`.

You probably want to use something that gives you more flexibility than `sed` for this. I would use `awk`. And you're un luck, because your use of a sane date format allows basic numeric or string comparison to determine order!  So, with your sample input:

```
$ awk -v d="20180101" '$4>=d' file
ERROR     8245001       000 20180515  171012    Patch output error in output
ERROR     8245001       000 20180515  171119    Patch output error in output
ERROR     8245001       000 20180515  171119    Patch output error in output
```

Or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v d="20180101" '$4>=d' c > c,$$ && mv c,$$ c
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` / `gawk` onliner:

```
gawk -v dt="$(date -d "6 month ago" +%Y%m%d)" '$4+0>=dt+0' /root/new/Logfile.log >> outputfile
```

Check  [*How awk Converts Between Strings and Numbers*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers)

Comment: What will use If I don't want to redirect output to outputfile. Means same file Logfile.log get updated (old entry get delete).

Comment: use https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html if your `gawk` supports it, otherwise you will need an auxiliary file